# Installing extra packages of Debian Wheezy from terminal (after a net install)

Tags: debian, apt

I've installed the small image of Debian Wheezy from [here](http://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst) but had to skip the mirror install of the extra packages.

Now that I have the command line how do I get the rest of the stuff?

When I tried `apt-get install ssh-server`, it told me to insert the CD.

Comment: one search first result on google http://ortuno2k.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/remove-cd-rom-from-apt-get-repositories-debian-6/

Comment: In the answers, `ftp.us.debian.org` is used as an mirror, I recommend `http.debian.net` which chooses automatically the best mirrors. See http://http.debian.net/ for more information.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the internet repositories, and remove the cdrom's ones, as root:

```
sed -i 's/deb\ cdrom/#deb cdrom/' /etc/apt/sources.list
sh -c "echo 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian $(lsb_release -sc) main contrib' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
## The following only for non-free repository
sh -c "echo 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian $(lsb_release -sc) non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
apt-get update
```

Then install the package you need. There's also the `-security` and `-update` repository you can add. If you don't have `sudo` you can use `su`.

Comment: sudo is not installed by default on debian.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the repositories file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove all and add this lines:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install ssh-server
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, comment out the line referring to the CD, and add these lines (or make sure they're uncommented):

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then do a `apt-get update` and try again.

If the US site is slow for you, you can substitute [a mirror that's closer to you](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list-full).